# Can I change DB table name from the default automatically on Django?

Tags: python, django, database

I would like to change the DB table names on Django1.9. I know we can change the standard issue with "db_table".

```
Class Foo_Bar:

    class Meta:
        db_table = "foo_bar"
```

But I need to write that in every single class and it is tiresome.
I want Django creates a table whose name is lower-cased class name automatically.
But I have no idea how to do.

I even tried to use

```
self.__class__.name__.lower()
```

but, I didn't know how Meta works well.

Any advice is helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: "I want Django creates a table whose name is lower-cased class name automatically" <<< Django does that automatically with "appname_modelname" in lower case. I don't think you can change this easily. So adding "db_table" is the only way to go.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. First, I tried to write using 

    __class.__name__

, but I didn't know what Meta is well, so I couldn't use it.

Comment: Ah, I cannot write magic method here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very hack-ish method but this code will give you the outer (since you want to get `Foo_Bar`, not `Meta`) class name:

```
import traceback

Class Foo_Bar:
    ...
    class Meta:
        db_table = traceback.extract_stack()[-2][2].lower()
```